Mental Asylum Movie
I was looking for a movie I saw around 1990-2010s. It may have been older, but it wasn't made after 2013, and it was in color and had relatively good special effects. If it helps, the special effects used were closer to those of Saw (2004) rather than to the obvious Total Recall (1990) special effects.
The movie was about a wo/man (I think s/he may have been a doctor) who was sent to a mental asylum. Perhaps it was for an audit or study.
However, after s/he had been there (or had regularly visited) for a while, s/he discovered that the asylum had a basement or underground area where creeps, disabled patients, and other strange patients were held. They were physically different from the patients on the upper levels of the asylum.
Long story short, they were unexpectedly released and attacked the wo/man.
In the end of the movie, it was revealed that the asylum staff knew what about the underground patients, but had been trying to hide them. The staff had not intended for the underground patients to be released. 

By any chance it can be Stonehearst Asylum (2014) or Madhouse (2004)

@AnkitSharma Madhouse! please answer the question. thanks!
